# How to save System.Media.DateEncoded in UWP video StorageFile

Tags: uwp, storagefile

For a given `StorageFile`, named file, I can retrieve some properties by calling

```
await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertiesToRetrieve)
```

Change them and save them properly

```
await file.Properties.SaveProperties(propertiesToSave)
```

However, I am getting a `The method or operation is not implemented` error in a `try/catch` block whenever I try to save the `System.Media.DateEncoded` property to a video file (MP4 and MOV), but i can read them without problem.

Is there a way to save such a property with the current API?

Thank you

**Added Info**

The DateTimeOffset comes from a DatePicker combined with a Timepicker, and it is injected in in a function similar to the one below. To simplify the code, I use below a hardcoded value for the DateTimeOffset. The exception is still thrown with the same message. I guarantee on my side that file is not null (not shown).

```
    public async Task<bool> SaveDateEncoded(StorageFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            var dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(2000, 09, 03, 3, 50, 13, new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));
            var props = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
            {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("System.Media.DateEncoded",dateTimeOffset),
            };
            await file.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync(props);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some properties are read-only by design and underlying property handler does not allow setting them even though it's technically possible. This might be one of them, especially if your changing other properties the same way succeeds. I don't think underlying Media Foundation MP4 shell property handler is documented to state exactly which properties are read-only.

Comment: @RomanR, you mean there is no way to know if a property is readonly? Yes the method works on other properties, no doubt.

Comment: How would it be technically possible, do you have some hints? Thanks

Comment: When I chose a MOV video file and set a value to the "System.Media.DateEncoded" property, then used SavePropertiesAsync method to save it, it worked well. After that, I can also read the value from the property. So can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: OK that is good news, I will provide this because I just cannot see yet how to solve this.

Comment: Done, here is also a sample video file https://github.com/Ponant/StorageFileQueryResultBug/blob/master/ImageSample/VID_20191007_164325.mp4

Comment: If you download another mp4 file from the web and use it to test again, will the same issue occur?

Comment: it happens with some MP4 and MOV files, but not all. Try out this video if you can it only 20MB and it should not work.

Comment: When I tested your video, I could reproduce this issue. What device did you use for recording this video? Does the same error occur when you test with all the videos recorded by this device?

Comment: Huawei P20 Lite (ANE-LX1). Checking your suggestion.

Comment: The problem also occurs with iphone 6s (MOV file), so this cannot be a one-device issue

Comment: I tested other Huawei MP4 files and it does not work neither. So both iphone 6s and Huawei P20 Lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting a The method or operation is not implemented error

This issue is fixed in Version 1903,1909.

Please see:

February 27, 2020—KB4535996 (OS Builds 18362.693 and 18363.693)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4535996/windows-10-update-kb4535996

> Addresses an issue with editing the properties of .mov files.

So you can install KB4535996 on your 1903/1909 machine and the issue will be resolved.

Comment: This package solves the problem but seems to break the app packaging. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/934967/uwp-error-failed-to-sign.html for a follow up

Comment: I am having the same problem again, but now with a MOV file. Even file explorer refuses to change the date, saying that this is a read-only property. You told me you tested it with MOV and that it worked, I also did so a month ago and it worked. So it seems to be a windows issue which is not fixed yet because KB4535996 has been removed (as it causes other problem as you most likely know). Let me now if possible